# what scope is required to determine state of matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Lets us assume some kind of material (that is known to us) to be in a uniform state (gas/liquid/solid). For example - water (meaning the material might contain several kinds of atoms), either as ice or as liquid, but not an ice cube floating in a cup of water.

Can we determine the state by observing a single atom? If not, can we do so by looking at an atom and it's closest neighbors? Or does it require a large number of atoms? Does the answer change if the material is made of a single kind of atom?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @sammygerbil I cam here to ask. But intuitively, i think there should be local effects.

Comment: In a crystal a single unit cell and the information that it is a crystal is enough for density functional calculations. Tight-binding calculations for solids are based on nearest neighbor orbital overlapping. A perfect gas is a non interacting system, so a single molecule gives a lot of information. Note that in all these cases, you have prior knowledge about the system. The reverse reasoning: getting the larger picture from the local interaction may or may not work: you will have a hard time knowing whether local interactions are fluctuations or a local signature of long range order.

Comment: It goes without saying that you came here to ask, but we expect you to demonstrate some prior effort to answer the question yourself. What do you mean by *local effects*? Do you think these effects will enable you to deduce the state of matter?

Answer (score 0):

the characteristics of the different phases of one substance- solid, liquid, and gas- have almost everything to do with the relationships between a single atom of it and its nearest neighbors. What this means is that if you had a single atom of a given substance in isolation- with no nearest neighbors at all- as, for instance, in the vacuum of space- there is no way you could tell by looking at it whether it represented an atom of a solid, liquid, or gas. those are emergent properties possessed by a large number of atoms aggregated together in each other's company.

Comment: I'm not talking about an isolated atom, i"m just asking how much should I zoom-in with my microscope. Could you provide an example? Preferably a quantitative one.

Comment: the only microscopes we have to do that job are atomic force microscopes (look up AFM) and they work only for solids.

Comment: but lets assume i have a microscope that can used for gases and liquids as well, or lets just focus on the physics here.

Comment: in liquids and gases, the atoms are in rapid motion. you need them to be standing still to resolve them as atoms.